# Removed account still appears in outlook 2013 left hand pane

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I deleted an email account in outlook 2013 and without closing outlook I created a new one. Subsequently the deleted account still appears on the left hand pane . Any ideas how I can get rid of it?
Because the account still appears on the left pane but not in the account setting email account list, I don't have the option of deleting it again.

I've tried removing the pst file using windows explorer but then outlook fails to start. Naturally I've googled the issue but can't find anything pertinent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try account settings and delete from this area. Otherwise redefine a new Outlook profile.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on ms website

> In case you have removed a POP account from the Outlook, the data file
>   associated with the account will not be removed automatically.   We
>   have to close the data file by right clicking on it. In case this
>   personal folder is set as default personal folder, then you may not be
>   able to close it. You must set a different data file as default data
>   file and then close it.   Open Outlook > Click on File > Account
>   settings > Data files > Choose a new data file > Click on default >
>   Select the problem data file and click on remove.

link [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/i-deleted-an-email-account-in-outlook-2010-but-the/ce63e90d-e988-4221-9d71-1a06afa92502?auth=1)